# How to run Laravel artisan command on AppFog?

Tags: php, command-line, laravel, appfog

How to run an artisan command on my Laravel app in AppFog?

I need to run commands like this:

```
php artisan down
php artisan up
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I can run Artisan commands within my app code, like this:

```
Artisan::call('down');
```

Reference: [Laravel Forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=45882#p45882)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can currently do so, other people seem pretty annoyed by this:

- http://feedback.appfog.com/forums/171983-appfog/suggestions/3385727-ssh-access

Perhaps a work around could be constructing a password protected part of your application that calls the artisian tasks directly?

Comment: May I do this? Could I execute a PHP file asynchronously and passing parameters to it, from another PHP file that runs by a browser?